# ASIHttprequest for log in authenticaion

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services, authentication, asihttprequest

i am using ASIHttprequest for login authentication [Here is the deme code](https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request)

The code i am trying is :

```
[self setRequest:[ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url1]];
[_request setUseKeychainPersistence:[useKeychain isOn]];
[_request setDelegate:self];
[_request setShouldPresentAuthenticationDialog:[useBuiltInDialog isOn]];
[_request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(topSecretFetchComplete:)];
[_request setDidFailSelector:@selector(topSecretFetchFailed:)];
[_request startAsynchronous];
[request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];
[_request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];
```

Request failed and Request complete methods

```
- (IBAction)topSecretFetchFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)theRequest{
   [responseField setText:[[request error] localizedDescription]];
   [responseField setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]];
}

- (IBAction)topSecretFetchComplete:(ASIHTTPRequest *)theRequest{
   [responseField setText:[request responseString]];
   [responseField setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]];
   NSLog(@"Response :%@",[request responseString]);
```

}

```
- (void)authenticationNeededForRequest:(ASIHTTPRequest *)theRequest{
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please Login" message:[request authenticationRealm] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK",nil];

[alertView addTextFieldWithValue:@"" label:@"Username"];
[alertView addTextFieldWithValue:@"" label:@"Password"];
[alertView show];
```

}

i am new to ios so please......
in this demo when i clock go one alert is popup but when i use my webservice its give the response like this

> Response :ASIHTTPRequest: 0xa846400

but do not popup the alertview for enter username and password

If any other Better Way to authenticate login please suggest me

i want to place login as rootview and after successfully login can enter in to app

thanks...

Comment: NSLog (@"The Response : %@"[TheReqest responseString]) NOT  NSLog(@"Response :%@",theRequest);

Comment: ASIhttp is a discontinued library.Use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Login Authentication ,using ASIFormDataRequest Follow the following STEPS

1) Create one webservice which can match User Name and Password from server and give the response **if** Username and Password is correct Give response "Success" **ELSE** "Fail".

For Example : https://www.yoursite.com/login1.php?username=%@&password=%@

2) Create one url using UsernameTextfield.text  and PasswordTextfield.text  like this

```
NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.yoursite.com/login1.php?username=%@&password=%@",Ustr,Pstr]];
```

Where Ustr and Pstr are NSString from Both text fields.

3) Create ASIFormDataRequest

```
- (IBAction)fetchTopSecretInformation:(id)sender{

    Ustr = User.text;
    Pstr  = Pass.text;

    NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.yoursite.com/login1.php?username=%@&password=%@",Ustr,Pstr]];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request1 = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url1];
    [request1 setUseKeychainPersistence:YES];
    request1.delegate = self;
    request1.shouldPresentCredentialsBeforeChallenge = YES;

    [request1 setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
    [request1 setPostValue:User.text forKey:@"User Name"];
    [request1 setPostValue:Pass.text forKey:@"Password"];
    [request1 setTimeOutSeconds:30];

    [request1 setDidFailSelector:@selector(topSecretFetchFailed:)];
    [request1 setDidFinishSelector:@selector(topSecretFetchComplete:)];
    [request1 startAsynchronous];
```

}

Connect this method with Sign In Button in xib.

```
- (IBAction)topSecretFetchFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)theRequest{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Error sending request to the server" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}

- (IBAction)topSecretFetchComplete:(ASIHTTPRequest *)theRequest{
    NSString *strResponse = [[theRequest responseString] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    strFinal = [theRequest responseString];
    NSLog(@"Sattus Code : %@",[theRequest responseString]);

    NSString *failStr = @"failed";
    NSString *successStr = @"successfully";

    if ([strFinal isEqualToString:successStr]) {
    ViewController *view = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];

   }else
        if ([strFinal isEqualToString:failStr]) {
            UIAlertView *AlertFail = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"LogIn Failed !" message:@"Wrong ID or Password" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
         [AlertFail show];
        }
}
```

So if success go  to next page otherwise Alert warning .....

Answer (score 1):

it some times happen when whitespace, special characters and new line characters  are in that response so  first trim that string and then print the response like bellow..

```
NSString *strResponse = [[theRequest responseString] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
NSLog(@"Response :%@",strResponse);
```

**UPDATE:**

```
- (NSString *)flattenHTML:(NSString *)html {

    NSScanner *theScanner;
    NSString *text = nil;
    theScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:html];

    while ([theScanner isAtEnd] == NO) {

        [theScanner scanUpToString:@"<" intoString:NULL] ; 

        [theScanner scanUpToString:@">" intoString:&text] ;

        html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@>", text] withString:@""];
    }
    //
    html = [html stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    return html;
}
```

use this method like bellow..

```
 NSString *strResponse = [[theRequest responseString] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
 NSString *strFinal = [self flattenHTML:strResponse];
 NSLog(@"Response :%@",strFinal);
```

Comment: which you get just paste here

Comment: Response :<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" id="sky">
  <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var _ttref = [];
    _ttref.push(['_setCookie']);
</script>



<title>
Login to Hire Freelancers, Outsource Jobs, Find Work | Freelancer.com
</title>
.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34615/discussion-between-denny-and-paras-joshi)